# Running PHP in Express

Tags: javascript, php, html, express, pug

I plan to run index.php in my express view. I am using express generator and this is my index.jade looks like.

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}

  script(src='js/jquery.min.js')
  script(type='text/javascript').
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#div').load('index.php');
    });
```

Here is what my index.php looks like

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>TalkInTee</title>

    <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js">      </script>

        <style>

</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="maindiv">

        <?php
            include 'tdesignAPI/new_applit.php';
        ?>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

My index.php is located on the same folder as my index.jade

I totally new in terms on using php. I only need to use this php for my shirt designer program. Can anyone help me on running this php code? Thank you so much.

Comment: That's a really weird way of doing it. Why would you blend Express and PHP like this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good or bad idea but what I need is to run that php code using express. I need express to generate some APIs. And as I have stated above, I am really a starter so please enlighten me.

Comment: Why is PHP even involved here?  Whatever logic you're using PHP for should just be done in Express and your Javascript template system of choice and things would likely be a lot more efficient and simpler.

Comment: @jfriend00 as I have said, I am really not good on using php. The only reason I use it is because of a github shirt designer repo that uses php and it suits my needs. If i have a choice not to choose php or convert it magically to JS then I would do it for sure.

Comment: Why don't you build your server with PHP instead of nodejs then if that's the code you have to start?  It's odd and inefficient to try to use pieces of two separate server environments.

Comment: as i have said again, i have zero experience on coding on php. I only need that code because it suits my needs.